# Java CallableStatement setDate value decreasing by 1 day

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have created a `callableStatement` and I am setting the date value using `setDate`.

But what happens is that the date value in the query is decreasing by 1 day for which I am not able to see the reason.

```
CallableStatement cStmt = connection.prepareCall(procedureCall);
Date localDate = Date.valueOf(updateUserProfileRequest.getDob().toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate());
cStmt.setDate(11, localDate);
System.out.println(("cStmt ==== >> "+cStmt); //outputs '1979-06-19'
System.out.println((localDate.toString()); //outputs 1979-06-20
```

Here `updateUserProfileRequest.getDob()` returns a `java.sql.Timestamp` object.

DB : MySql

Log :  `cStmt ==== >> HikariProxyCallableStatement@21434634312 wrapping com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement: CALL proc_test0('1979-06-29')`

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `setObject(11, updateUserProfileRequest.getDob().toLocalDateTime().toLocalDate())` instead of trying to convert to the legacy `java.sql.Date` class first? All recent JDBC drivers should support `LocalDate` with `setObject`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I tried with the above approach also, but then also it decrements the value of day by 1.

Comment: Are you sure that your application (JVM) and the database are in the same timezone?